# Stuck on button template with texbox

Tags: wpf, templates, button, textbox

I have a button template shown bellow, in this case when the text is entered the button stays the same size, and it works ok. However I want just a border, so when I try to add that ellipse inside the thumb to get the border, and try typing text in the textbox, when the text becomes larger than the button suddenly it covers the button with a white background, i don't know why this is happening, any help would be appreciated.

```
        <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                    <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                </ControlTemplate> 
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid>
                        <Thumb x:Name="outerThumbResize" Cursor="SizeNESW" Background="Red" Height="50" Width="50"/>

                        <!--<Ellipse x:Name="innerCircle" Fill="White" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".8" ScaleY=".8"/>
                            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                        </Ellipse>-->


                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Visibility="Collapsed" TextAlignment="Center" PreviewKeyUp="textBox_PreviewKeyUp" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Thumb x:Name="innerThumb" Background="Transparent" DragDelta="nodeThumb_DragDelta" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                            <Thumb.RenderTransform>
                                <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9"/> 
                            </Thumb.RenderTransform>
                        </Thumb>

                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: i solved it using the stroke thickness of the ellipse in the template.

Comment: Post it as an answer and accept it when you're allowed or delete the question

Comment: No problem :) That way other people can easily see what a solution to the problem is etc.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as the questions answer by clicking the big checkmark next to it.

Comment: @Lerxst thanks it wasn't letting me for some time since I am new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it using the stroke thickness of the ellipse in the template.